# Distribuir meu app via email

Tags: android, mobile, xamarin

Fiz a distribuição do meu App, compilando em release e depois a opção Arquivar. Bem, gerou a chave e vários arquivos. Agora como eu faço para enviar por email para meu cliente e também colocar em meu site. O que ele vai pegar para instalar em seu smartphoe? Segui esse [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/)

Comment: gerou o apk não? se sim, esse é o arquivo que deve mandar, teste no seu proprio celular antes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve enviar por e-mail o arquivo de extensão .APK, assim que seu cliente abrir ele no android, irá instalar. Pode ser necessário ter que alterar as configurações do android, permitindo instalar apps desconhecidos.

Answer (score 3):

Via e-mail seria você enviar o arquivo anexo para o destinatário, e seu cliente abrir utilizando um dispositivo Android.

Para disponibilizar em seu site, você pode optar por subir o arquivo em um servidor e colocar a URL em seu site...